# Get index of an item from a group of identical items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Say I have a group of HTML tags that are identical, e.g.:

```
<div id="stuff">
<span class="foo">Foo</span>
<span class="foo">Foo</span>
<span class="foo">Foo</span>
<span class="foo">Foo</span>
<span class="foo">Foo</span>
</div>
```

I'm attaching an onclick event to the spans like so:

```
$(".foo").click(function() {
    // stuff
});
```

In my onclick event, I want to get the index of the clicked element, so for example, if I clicked the 3<sup>rd</sup> span, I want the index to be 3. How would I do that? Normally, I'd iterate over `$("#stuff")` and compare the items to the clicked item, but in this case, they are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **HTML**

```
<div id="stuff">
<span class="foo">Foo</span>
<span class="foo">Foo</span>
<span class="foo">Foo</span>
<span class="foo">Foo</span>
<span class="foo">Foo</span>
</div>
```

## **Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.foo').click(function(){
        var x = $(this).index();
        alert(x);
    });
});
```

working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Jj72A/

Answer (score 4):

Get the index by using:-

Indexes are zero based relative to its siblings. SO for the 3rd element you will get the index as 2.

```
$(".foo").click(function() {
    alert($(this).index());
}
```

Read about [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dmrha/)

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this:

```
$(".foo").click(function(){
    alert(jQuery.inArray(this,$(".foo")));
});
```